# How to get rid of using ElementName in WPF bindings in XAML

Tags: wpf, data-binding, binding, .net-4.0, dependency-properties

I am building a WPF application and I have some DependencyProperties in my window's codebehind (actually a big bunch of them). I want to bind a textbox to one of these string values. If I use `{Binding ObjectName}` it just doesn't work and it complains about not finding the property in the output. If I use `{Binding ObjectName, ElementName=window}` (where `window` is my Window's instance name), it works. But I have lots of bindings and I don't want to use the ElementName property each time. Is there any shortcut that will default all the element names to the window objects, as all of my bindings have the same element?

Thanks,
Can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default source of a binding is `FrameworkElement.DataContext` so you have to set the `DataContext` property of your window to the instance of your window e.g. `DataContext = this;`

Comment: I tried to set the window's DataContext to `DataContext="{RelativeSource Self}"` but it didn't work. When I tried to remove the ElementName, it fell back to the default value, breaking the binding.

Comment: oh, my bad. I changed it to `DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"` now it works. thank you.